# Prove that for $A, B, C \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ if sets $A \triangle B$ and $B \triangle C$ are finite then $A \triangle C$ is also finite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Like in the title, we need to prove that:
$$\forall A, B,C \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \quad (A \triangle B \text{ is finite } \wedge B \triangle C \text{ is finite}) \implies A \triangle C \text{ is finite } $$
We can write the definition: $A \triangle B = A \setminus B  \cup  B \setminus A $. Now we can see that the sets $A \setminus B, C \setminus B, B \setminus A, B \setminus C$ are finite. We have to prove that also $A \setminus C, C \setminus A$ is finite.

I tried to write $C = (C \setminus B) \cup (B \cap C)$, $A = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \cap A)$ so we could prove $(B \cap C) \triangle (B \cap A)$ is finite, but it doesn't bring me anywhere.

Comment: Prove first that $A\Delta C\subseteq (A\Delta B)\cup(B\Delta C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try and guess what's
$$
(A\mathbin{\triangle}B)\mathbin{\triangle}(B\mathbin{\triangle}C)
$$